# Loop through mysql array and for each variabe create a session

Tags: php, mysql, session, loops

I have two types of users, Manager and employees. 
Currently I have a session working when the manager is logged on. To allow the manager to view each individual employees i need to  create another session for each employee, to remeber which employee he has clicked on.

How would I do this, how would I remember the ID of the employeer?

Comment: your question is not clear. Please be more precise as to what output are you looking for

Comment: what do you need to have in your session counter

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can't have multiple active sessions to one client. `session_start()` starts a new session or resumes an existing one (look it up in the manual).

Comment: I have cleared it up a little bit, hope that helps :)

Comment: @user3506938 so what is not working

Comment: currently it displays all the pupils results, I want it to display the pupil the teacher has clicked on. Is this possible?

Comment: Well, the `click` I guess is a link/button, that DOES contain the student_id. So just extract that student_id from the button/link and add it to the session `$_SESSION['counter'] = 'the clicked value'`

Comment: Thank you !! I 've managed to parse the ID through the URL , no need to use sessions

Answer (score 1):

To parse a single ID from page to page - there is no need to use Sessions.

Just parse it through the URL. For Example:

```
<a href='page2.php?id=248>link to page2</a>
```

then to retrieve this you will need on the other page :

```
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
```

That worked for me!

But be careful you don't want to be parsing passwords and other secure information through the URL

Answer (score -2):

Try creating session variable like this

```
$_SESSION['counter'. $studentID]
```

Comment: This is not better than arrays

Comment: `counter[]` is still OK. The user can check the values in the array to achieve its goal.

Comment: but how do i know which user the teacher has clicked on? At the moment it only shows ll of the students, not the one they clicked on.

Comment: I suggest to keep that in $_GET or $_POST rather than session

Comment: @user3506938 that's because you select all users and add them to the session. Select the ones that he clicked? Maybe trigger $_SESSION['counter'] on click of the teacher?